# I have a problem connecting to phpmyadmin using valet

Tags: phpmyadmin, valet

I have just installed Laravel Valet for Windows and I have succesfuly linked phpmyadmin with the localhost server but when I want to connect with phpmyadmin( which is for me pma.test) it refuses the connection.

I have already tried to change some authentication values in the config.inc.php file in the map of phpmyadmin but none of them seem to work.

The error phpmyadmin is giving me: 1."mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".
2." Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed." 
3." phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server."

Error (phpmyadmin) :

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

i have the same error on Mac.
I also notices that mysql is not working in the terminal.

Comment: this should be a comment as it doesnt really answer the question...

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the my.ini file. It's situated in the C:\xampp\mysql\bin\ folder.
2. Go to the [mysqld] section.
3. In the [mysqld] section type skip-grant-tables.
4. Save and close.
5. Restart xampp.

I hope this helps.